Flickering issue due to guard redirection in Angular 17
I'm encountering an issue in my Angular 17 application with server-side rendering (SSR) where, upon reloading a page, the login page briefly appears and then disappears. This behavior shouldn't occur, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause.
I have an authentication guard set up as follows:
export const authGuard = (): CanActivateFn => {
  return route => {
    const auth = inject(AuthService);
    const router = inject(Router);

    if (!auth.session()) {
      const queryParams = { redirect: route.url };

      return router.createUrlTree(['login'], { queryParams });
    }

    return true;
  };
};

Interestingly, if I change the guard to return false instead of redirecting with router.createUrlTree(['login'], { queryParams }), the issue is resolved, but obviously, I want to redirect users to the login page when authentication is required.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue before with Angular 17 and SSR, or can offer guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this?
For your information, I manage authentication with Supabase, and I have auth.session() instantiated."
function initializeSessionFactory(auth: AuthService) {
  return () => auth.initializeSession();
}

export const provideSupabaseAuthInitializer = () => {
  return {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeSessionFactory,
    deps: [AuthService],
    multi: true,
  };
};


I would guess that when this code runs server side, it gets a redirect, renders a login page, and returns it, on the FE then it shows what the server returns.

Where do you use this guard? Do you have any other guards in your app? How does your authService look like?

Possibly related to this known issue of Angular 17? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26323#issuecomment-1971390348

It seems to me that your app doesnt wait for initialization of auth. I guess your authService.InitializeSession() method returns observable. But in your factory you're not returning that observable, in fact, you're returning a function. But factory already is a function, it shouldnt return one.
So I believe you should change it to
function initializeSessionFactory(auth: AuthService) {
  return auth.initializeSession();
}

This way you return observable from your factory, and app initializer should wait for this observavle to complete before starting rest of application
If it doesnt work please provide some information on how your authService works
